# TypeScript Generics column.id should be within row[key]

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm writing a TypeScript Interface for Tables:

```
interface Column {
    id: string;
    label: string;
}

interface Data {
    [key: string]: string;
}

interface Table {
    columns: Column[];
    data: Data[];
}
```

I'd like to restrict the allowed values for `Column.id`: Each `Column.id` must have a matching `Data.key`. (But: **Not** every `Data.key` must have a matching `Column.id`)

### Examples:

This should be **allowed**, because every `Column.id` has a matching `Data.key`.

```
columns: [
  { id: 'foo', label: 'foo' },
  { id: 'bar', label: 'bar' }
]

data: [
  { foo: '123', bar: '456', baz: '789' }
]
```

But this should **not be allowed**, because `Data[foo]` doesn't exist.

```
columns: [
  { id: 'foo', label: 'foo' }
]

data: [
  { bar: '456' }
]
```

How is it possible to write a `Table` interface, which applies these constraints?

Comment: You can't restrict the value of the parameter of interface but its type. You might find solution to restrict it via compilation, but it won't take effect on runtime. So to achieve that, you have to restrict a class the implement the interface which take control over this problem.

Comment: I should only restrict at compile time. That's everything I expect from TypeScript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a concrete type that represents this constraint, but you *can* use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) along with a helper function to infer a generic type that enforces that constraint.

Let's extend the definitions of `Column`, `Data`, and `Table` to be generic in the string properties we care about:

```
interface Column<K extends string = string> {
  id: K,
  label: string;
}

type Data<K extends string = string> = Record<K, string>

interface Table<K extends string = string, L extends K = K> {
  columns: Column<L>[];
  data: Data<K>[];
}
```

Note how a valid `Table<K, L>`, assuming `K` and `L` are unions of [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) and that `K` is as narrow as it can be, expresses the constraint you want.  Since `L extends K`, it means that `columns['id']` must be a subtype of `keyof data`.

The following helper function will do the inference for you:

```
const asTable = <K extends string, L extends K>(x: Table<K, L>) => x;
```

Okay, let's see if it works:

```
// no error
const goodTable = asTable({
  columns: [
    { id: 'foo', label: 'foo' },
    { id: 'bar', label: 'bar' }
  ],
  data: [
    { foo: '123', bar: '456', baz: '789' }
  ]    
})

// error ... Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'
const badTable = asTable({
  columns: [
    { id: 'foo', label: 'foo' }
  ]
  ,
  data: [
    { bar: '456' }
  ]
})
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. That's awesome! I've played a bit with your code and came up with another solution (see my answer below). I'm not sure what are the pros and cons. Maybe you can tell me `:)`

Comment: If you call for example: let temp = 'baz' as 'foo'; and use it inside columns it is still good right?

Comment: If someone is writing `'baz' as 'foo'` (in other words: f*cking up the code on purpose), then it's his own fault. I just want to provide type guidelines using TypeScript interfaces. I know that you can circumvent all those types if you really want to: Just write `any` everywhere. But in this case no typed language in the world can save you from hell.

Comment: @BenjaminM, right, but you can achieve that by constructing a class that handles these errors, I was just checking cause  I wasnt sure. nothing more. glad you got your answer. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, which seems to work.

I'm not sure what are the pros and cons compared to @jcalz version.

Maybe someone can leave a comment and explain the differences `:)`

```
interface Column<K extends string> {
    id: K;
    label: string;
}

interface Props<D extends {[key: string]: string}> {
    columns: Array<Column<keyof D & string>>;
    data: D[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe easier base on @jcalz

```
interface Column<K extends string = string> {
  name: K;
  friendly_name: string;
  type: string;
}

type Data<K extends string = string> = Record<K, any>;

interface UniformedData<K extends string = string> {
  columns: Column<K>[];  
  //rows: Data<ValueOf<Pick<Column<K>, 'name'>>>[];//type ValueOf<T>=T[keyof T];
  rows: Data<Column<K>['name']>[];
}

// Runtime type-inferring must on funcs
export const asTable = <K extends string>(x: UniformedData<K>) => x;

const check = asTable({
  columns: [{ name: 'c1', friendly_name: 'C1', type: 'string' }],
  rows: [{ c2: 'x' }], // error!
});
···
```